# AWS cognito not storing cookies in prod

Tags: cookies, next.js, amazon-cognito, netlify

**Context:**

I am using the amazon-cognito-identity-js SDK for authentication, as I am not using amplify for this project, only need to use cognito services. So far locally, I can do pretty much every fine, tokens come back and using the `new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CookieStorage()` it seems to be to store cookies locally using `({ domain: 'localhost', secure: 'false' })`.

Also using nextjs v10.0.6

**Problem**
I tried to deploy the app to netlify and after installing it gives me back the tokens but does not store them in cookies on my browser.

Here is the snippet of code that I am using to sign in a user, there is a use case where the user was created by the admin, and will be forced to change password, thus the redirect to `/changePassword`

Any guidance would be amazing! My suspicion is that I am not configuring the domain right... but have tried every combination such as, removing the https, only including the autoGenerated subdomain part, etc

```js
export const userPoolData = (): ICognitoUserPoolData => ({
  UserPoolId: process.env.USER_POOL_ID || '',
  ClientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID || '',
  Storage: new CookieStorage({
    domain: 'https://<autoGeneratedURL>.netlify.app',
    secure: true,
    expires: 10,
    path: '/',
  }),
});
```

```js
const authenticationData = {
    Username: username,
    Password: password,
  };

  const authenticationDetails = new AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);

  const poolData = userPoolData();

  const userPool = new CognitoUserPool(poolData);
  console.log({ poolData });

  const userData = {
    Username: username,
    Pool: userPool,
    Storage: new CookieStorage({
      domain: 'https://<autoGeneratedURL>.netlify.app',
      secure: true,
      expires: 10,
      path: '/',
    }),
  };

  const cognitoUser: CognitoUser = new CognitoUser(userData);
  const userTokens: Pick<ResponseMessage, 'tokens'> = {};
  console.log(authenticationData);

  const authResponse = new Promise(() => {
    cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
      onSuccess: (result) => {
        console.log(result);
        router.push({ pathname: '/' });
      },
      onFailure: (error) => {
        console.log(error);
        if (error.code !== 'InvalidParameterException' && error.code !== 'NotAuthorizedException') {
          router.push({ pathname: '/changePassword', query: { username, password } });
        }
      },
    });
  });

  try {
    await authResponse;
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      success: false,
      code: 500,
      error,
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone runs into this, it turned out my suspicion was right and the fault was in the `domain` pattern, for a netlify app it should be configured as `domain: <autoGeneratedURL>.netlify.app`